# Mobx makeAutoObservable not binding this

Tags: reactjs, observable, store, mobx, mobx-react

I've built a basic counter React app with a simple MobX store. I was able to create an observable MobX status using `makeObservable` but for some reason when I try to use `makeAutoObservable` I get the error

`Cannot read property 'counter' of undefined`

How am I using `makeAutoObservable` incorrectly?

store

```
import { makeAutoObservable, makeObservable, action, observable } from "mobx";

class SampleStore {
  counter = 0;

  constructor(arg) {
    makeAutoObservable(this);
    // makeObservable(this, {
    //   counter: observable,
    //   increment: action.bound,
    //   decrement: action.bound,
    // });
  }

  increment() {
    this.counter++;
    return this.counter;
  }

  decrement() {
    this.counter--;
    return this.counter;
  }
}

export default SampleStore;
```

useStore hook

```
import { createContext, useContext } from "react";

import SampleStore from "./SampleStore";

export const store = {
  sampleStore: new SampleStore(),
};

export const StoreContext = createContext(store);

export const useStore = () => {
  return useContext(StoreContext);
};
```

provider

```
import { store, StoreContext } from "./stores";
import Index from "./layout/Index";

function App() {
  return (
    <StoreContext.Provider value={store}>
      <Index />
    </StoreContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

React component

```
import { useStore } from "../stores";
import { observer } from "mobx-react";

const Index = (props) => {
  const store = useStore();
  const {
    sampleStore: { counter, increment, decrement },
  } = store;
  return (
    <>
      <h1>MobX and React.js example</h1>
      <p>{counter}</p>
      <button onClick={increment}>+</button>
      <button onClick={decrement}>-</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default observer(Index);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It throws because your methods losing context (`this`) upon invocation (because you have destructured them).

It was working with `makeObservable` because you were using `action.bound` which autobinds method to the instance context.

If you want same functionality with `makeAutoObservable` you need to use arrow functions, like that:

```
class SampleStore {
  counter = 0;

  constructor(arg) {
    makeAutoObservable(this);
  }

  // Make it arrow function
  increment = () => {
    this.counter++;
    return this.counter;
  }
  
  // Make it arrow function
  decrement = () => {
    this.counter--;
    return this.counter;
  }
}
```

Alternatively you can also use `autoBind` option for `makeAutoObservable`:

```
constructor(arg) {
  makeAutoObservable(this, {}, { autoBind: true });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use autoBind: true in options of makeAutoObservable:

```
constructor(arg) {
  makeAutoObservable(this, {}, { autoBind: true });
}
```

This will automatically bind all your actions - so you won't loose the context on destructuring

Answer (score 0):

Try not to destructure the store like that. <s>When destructuring, any primitive variables will remain at the latest values and won't be observable anymore.</s>
You will also need to `bind` the click methods back to the store.

```
import { useStore } from "../stores";
import { observer } from "mobx-react";

const Index = (props) => {
  const {sampleStore:store} = useStore();

  return (
    <>
      <h1>MobX and React.js example</h1>
      <p>{store.counter}</p>
      <button onClick={store.increment.bind(store)}>+</button>
      <button onClick={store.decrement.bind(store)}>-</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default observer(Index);
```

Comment: `When destructuring, any primitive variables will remain at the latest values and won't be observable anymore.` this is not true, in that case it does not matter when you destructure, because your whole component is observer already, any destructure will be picked up. It would be true if you wanted to assign new values, but if you just need to observe then it does not matter

Comment: @Danila you are right about the `store.count` my bad.